# Allow location service in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

i am making an app in which I want user's location. I am using this code -

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
```

If user's don't allow there location then next time when user's open app then I am using this code for allow user's location -

```
 if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && 
       [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        NSLog(@"enable");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"disable");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
    }
```

But this is not work in iOS SDK 5.1 . So I want that every time when app become in foreground then if location service is disable then how to gave pop up of Allow location service.

Answer (score 2):

The settings app URL scheme is not longer available, you will just have to present the user with an `UIAlertView` or present a `UIViewController` modally that tells the user to switch on the location services for your app.

You can't really force the allow location dialog, it just pops up the first time.